# Make WPF Usercontrol resize entirely

Tags: c#, wpf, resize

In my application I have one frame resource and lots of icons resources. All of them are Path types. I would like to make a Usercontrol using the frame and one icon. The image bellow shows it better than any words:

[image]

I tried to make two grids, one overlapping another. On the icon grid I set the margins so the icon could fit correctly. But when I use this control in another place and resize it WPF tries to keep the margin values I set if it's too small the icon disappears from the frame. Is there any way to achieve this in WPF or do I have to duplicate all my icon paths to include the frame?

Comment: Wrap your `UserControl` content inside a `ViewBox`. This will allow your content to **scale**.

Comment: @MikeEason Thanks, that solved the problem. Please put that as an answer so I could accept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can wrap your `UserControl` content inside a `ViewBox`. This will allow your content to **scale** correctly when the control is resized.